# Option value doesn't keep and display after selecting

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on the homepage of [this site](http://www.asiamodeldirect.com/).

I added to 2 selections, one for `country` and one for `province`.

It works, but after selecting, the data doesn't keep and display anymore.

Can anybody help me to inspect and solve this problem?

Comment: add all relevant in OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done an inspection and it seems that the data is being retained but you are just not able to see it since the `color` inherited is `#fff`. If you change the `color` attribute to `#000` or something of your choice, it would then be visible.

So just change the font color of your select.

[image: Inspection of your home page before any change]

After disabling inherit:

[image: After disabling the inherit - inspection]

Comment: Happy to help :)